# How to perform MySQL spatial buffer function successfully?

Tags: mysql, spatial-query

Does anyone ever use MySQL spatial buffer function successfully?
I've read the documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-that-create-new-geometries-from-existing-ones.html#function_buffer

As stated in the documentation, buffer function has 2 parameters. The first one is geometry typed, the second one is distance.

I've try to make a geometry variable

```
mysql> set @g1 = geomfromtext('POINT(1 1)');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then, to ensure that my variable is correctly set, I perform a query. If the variable not correctly set, such a query will return NULL. In this case, it is confirmed that my variable is correctly set

```
mysql> select astext(@g1);
+-------------+
| astext(@g1) |
+-------------+
| POINT(1 1)  |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I run a query to select a buffer as stated in documentation

```
mysql> select astext(buffer(@g1, 5));
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION module_devel.buffer does not exist
```

Do I miss something here?

**EDIT** Sorry guys, I think I miss this:

> 12.17.5.3.2. Spatial Operators
>
> OpenGIS proposes a number of other functions that can produce
>   geometries. They are designed to implement spatial operators.
>   **These functions are not implemented in MySQL.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23964) bug report maybe. Which MySQL server are you using? Maybe you should upgrade to [5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-nutshell.html).

Comment: I use 5.5.24. I'll try to upgrade. Thanks for your answer